# Why do I need to create an IOTA instance to use the library functions?

Tags: javascript

Let the IOTA node instance be `iota` variable in the following context:

```
var IOTA=require("./node_modules/iota.lib.js/lib/iota")
var iota=new IOTA({ 'provider': 'https://iotanode.us:443'})
```

If I want to make a digest of a `SEED="ABC...XYZ"`, I do the following:

```
var digest=iota.multisig.getDigest(SEED,0,2) // Retuns the digest as a string
```

Why do I have to use the IOTA node instead of the library functions themselves?

For example:

```
var multisig=require("./node_modules/iota.lib.js/lib/multisig")
var alt_digest=multisig.getDigest(SEED,0,2) // Retuns and Object
```

I know that when I use `getNewAddress()` it will use the node to get a valid one, but why can't I generate a digest without a node?

Thank you.